# How do I get the API Live info for my VirtueMart3 in Joomla?

Tags: paypal, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

Using a Joomla website, I have a VirtueMart3 with a plugin called [PayPal Payments Pro 3D](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/payments/paypal-payments-pro-3d-secure-detail). This plugins request a **API Live Username**, **API Live Password** and a **API Live Signature** and links it to the Paypal account.

I created an application at this address "https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications" , and after the application was approved, they sent me a "Sandbox ID"and a "Live App ID".

What is a "Live App ID"?

How do I get a **API Live Username**, **API Live Password** and a **API Live Signature**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LIVE APP ID is provided to you when you create a [Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) Application.
You will need to use this APP-ID for making Adaptive Payment API calls.

**LIVE:**

You can get your API credentials at : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_get-api-signature&generic-flow=true (by logging with your paypal account credentials).

**Sandbox:**

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_get-api-signature&generic-flow=true

Comment: Hi, do I use the same link to get the sandbox id?

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_get-api-signature&generic-flow=true